# How to send shell commands via SSH without opening an new connection each time?

Tags: shell, ssh, blacklist

I'd like to send several shell commands via SSH to a server. Currently this looks like the following:

```
echo "copy file on server"
ssh user@server "cp file1 file2"

echo "rename file on server"
ssh user@server "mv file2 file3"

echo "generate folder on server"
ssh user@server "mkdir files"

echo "syncing files to server"
rsync ...

echo "do some other stuff"
ssh user@server "touch filex"
```

After doing this a couple of times, I was blacklisted since I had too many open connections / opened too many connections.

Is there a way to avoid beeing blacklisted (e.g. opening a single SSH-handle, send commands, and close the handle again)?

The Problem is, that some commands need to be executed locally (e.g. the `rsync`-command) while others need to be executed on the server. And the two kinds of commands are intermingled.

Comment: Why don't you just ssh into the server by `ssh user@server` and then execute those commands, and exit the server again?

Comment: There is one step that where I'd like to `rsync` files from my local machine to the server. If there was a way to tell rsync "take files from the working directory of the local machine that started the SSH connection", that would be fine.

Comment: rsync on your local machine will use SSH by default to transfer the files to the remote host.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a sequence of commands you know in advance a very simple solution is to use the sequential `&&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

I like to do it like this:

```
cat <<eot | ssh user@host bash
cp /tmp/a /tmp/b
mv /tmp/b /tmp/c
#etc
eot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following:

```
scp run.sh targethost:/tmp/.
ssh targethost /tmp/run.sh

ssh targethost 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3'

ssh targethost 'cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3'
```

I would sometimes recommend copying a script if it is a complex operation.  Also, using the logical AND is better then just issuing multiple commands if one is dependent on the other, i.e. changing directories before removing files, etc.